# Pipe file directly to AWS SSM parameter store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Just curious on how do i pipe file directly to aws ssm parameter store? e.g.

```
# Put into ssm parameter store
cat my_github_private.key | aws ssm put-parameter --region ap-southeast-1 --name MY_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY --type SecureString --key-id alias/aws/ssm --value ??? 
# And read it back 
aws ssm get-parameter --region ap-southeast-1 --name MY_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY --with-decryption --query Parameter.Value --output text > my_github_private.key.1
# Two should be identical
diff my_github_private.key my_github_private.key.1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Rather than taking the value from `stdin` can you directly add to the command line arguments?

```
aws ssm put-parameter \
    --region ap-southeast-1 \
    --name MY_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY \
    --type SecureString \
    --key-id alias/aws/ssm \
    --value file://my_github_private.key
```

Note: `--value "$(cat my_github_private.key)"` also works

Comment: Another response from Github [aws-cli repo] (https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3132):

`aws ssm put-parameter \
    --region ap-southeast-1 \
    --name MY_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY \
    --type SecureString \
    --key-id alias/aws/ssm \
    --value file://path/to/my_github_private.key`
Both of them work. Thanks guys.

Comment: I found that the ```--name``` parameter is what shows up in the AWS console and what can be used to get the parameter back. If you are happy with the default KMS encryption, then you would not need to provide ```--key-id``` parameter, per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/put-parameter.html).

Answer (score 2):

IF you are using terraform:

```
data "local_file" "yourkeyfile" {
    filename = "keys/yourkey.pem"
}
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "aresource-name-for-your-key" {
  name  = "/the/ssm/key"
  type  = "SecureString"
  value = "${data.local_file.yourkeyfile.content}"
}
```

Remember to crypt yourkey.pem for example using [blackbox](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox)

Answer (score 1):

@tkwargs,
how to get only value from key.json file and example

```
aws ssm put-parameter \
    --region ap-southeast-1 \
    --name MY_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY \
    --type SecureString \
    --key-id alias/aws/ssm \
    --value "$(cat my_github_private.json file and get value only)"
```

Comment: finally got the value using jq -r '.private_key' ,
aws ssm put-parameter \
    --region ap-southeast-1 \
    --name MY_GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY \
    --type SecureString \
    --key-id alias/aws/ssm \
    --value "$(cat my_github_private.json | jq -r '.value.key')"